# C# SQL Server query

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is code segment that I have written in C#. `Mobile` and `Name` are columns in my table.
The problem is that there is something wrong with format of my query. Is the syntax correct if we want to connect two queries in C # using OR?

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Contact Management] WHERE
         Mobile='"+Convert.ToInt32(txtSearch.Text)+"' OR Name='"+txtSearch.Text+"'",con);
```

Comment: Not correct at all you should not have the `txtSearch.Text` wrapped around any quotes what so ever.. I would personally look into using `Parameterized Query` as well

Comment: but if I remove the code segment after OR then it is working....that is after removing the OR part I can atleast select where mobile= some value...so the quotes is not creating any problem I think so....

Comment: you need to use parameters to insert user data into sql queries...

Answer (score 9):

No, that syntax is not correct. It's vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You need to build it like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Contact Management] WHERE
     Mobile= @Search OR Name= @Search")
SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Search", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtSearch.Text;
```

You could also write the query this way:

```
SELECT * FROM [Contact Management] WHERE @Search IN (Mobile, Name)
```

Comment: keeping the sql injection part aside is there any way without using parametrized queries.... I am a beginner so it is very difficult to understand....

Comment: Parameterized queries are the _only_ acceptable way to do this without running in sql injection issues, and I won't help you write vulnerable code.

Answer (score 5):

As usual, never use string concatenation to build sql command. Use parametrized queries

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM [Contact Management] WHERE Mobile=@mobile OR Name=@name";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", Convert.ToInt32(txtSearch.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtSearch.Text);
SqlDataAdapter da= new SqlDataAdapter (cmd);
```

The parametrized query will save your database from Sql Injection Attacks, but also from problems in parsing your input text. What if in the search text you have a single quote? You will get a syntax error with concatenation.

However, let me say that your code will fail before this. If you have a number in your txtSearch, then everything will work, but if you have a string. converting to a number with Convert.ToInt32 will fail. Better to use

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
string query;
int numSearch;
if(Int32.TryParse(txtSearch.Text, out numSearch))
{
   query = "SELECT * FROM [Contact Management] WHERE Mobile=@p1";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", numSearch);
}
else
{
   query = "SELECT * FROM [Contact Management] WHERE Name=@p1";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtSearch.Text);
}
cmd.CommandText = query;
....
```